# Ubuntu 20.04 : boot and startup slower

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup, performance

I have a laptop
HP EliteBook 820 G3
RAM 8Go
µP i5-6300 2,4GHz x 4
Gaphique Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
SSD 512Go

and only Ubuntu 20.04 4 LTS   64 bits  from scratch.

Boot and startup reach 2mn now.
With dmesg issues start at ~6s about bluetooth and the next message is 95s after.

Error seems to be for me between 5 and 7s.
Could you help me ?

**Part of dmesg**

```
gb@gb-elite:~/Bureau$ dmesg
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xea, date = 2021-01-25
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.13.0-40-generic (buildd@ubuntu) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1-generic 5.13.19)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=56e264bb-e854-4b2f-817a-876f814cd75c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
.
.
.
.

[    5.892866] loop13: detected capacity change from 0 to 509456
[    5.907382] ee1004 1-0050: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
[    5.921992] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    5.928952] loop14: detected capacity change from 0 to 337424
[    5.930180] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    5.952074] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 00000000519e5898 (20210331/exresop-557)
[    5.952087] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20210331/dswexec-431)

[    5.952096] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [WVPO]:
[    5.952098]   Local1: 00000000a6f52a93 <Obj>           Buffer(12) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

[    5.952112] Initialized Arguments for Method [WVPO]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    5.952113]   Arg0:   00000000ae6c4501 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000004
[    5.952119]   Arg1:   00000000519e5898 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000

[    5.952127] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WVPO due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    5.952137] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WMPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    5.954430] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 000000001c13ca4f (20210331/exresop-557)
[    5.954439] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20210331/dswexec-431)

[    5.954449] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [WVPO]:
[    5.954450]   Local1: 00000000cb3cc26f <Obj>           Buffer(136) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

[    5.954464] Initialized Arguments for Method [WVPO]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    5.954465]   Arg0:   0000000031cf5673 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000080
[    5.954471]   Arg1:   000000001c13ca4f <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000

[    5.954480] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WVPO due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    5.954490] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WMPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    5.954546] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input12
[    5.960471] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    5.979058] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.979063] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.979596] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 8000C-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.002201] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000063391e9d (20210331/exresop-557)
[    6.002209] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20210331/dswexec-431)

[    6.002215] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [WVPO]:
[    6.002216]   Local1: 00000000a6f52a93 <Obj>           Buffer(136) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

[    6.002225] Initialized Arguments for Method [WVPO]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    6.002225]   Arg0:   00000000027c7fe8 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000080
[    6.002229]   Arg1:   0000000063391e9d <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000

[    6.002234] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WVPO due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    6.002240] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMIV.WMPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    6.008883] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.008903] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    6.008904] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.008908] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.008910] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.008913] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.023999] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    6.024028] loop15: detected capacity change from 0 to 226640
[    6.027735] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    6.031942] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    6.031946] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    6.031947] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    6.031948] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    6.031950] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain psys 2^-14 Joules
[    6.034550] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    6.034554] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    6.034555] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    6.034557] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    6.034558] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    6.034559] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    6.036977] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    6.040511] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    6.056845] psmouse serio3: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5720], y [..4836]
[    6.072829] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x204
[    6.076461] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    6.076498] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    6.079747] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    6.080838] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.081371] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.086106] psmouse serio3: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1332..], y [1146..]
[    6.086117] psmouse serio3: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN3039 SYN0100 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    6.097594] loop16: detected capacity change from 0 to 1277392
[    6.119679] checking generic (d0000000 410000) vs hw (e0000000 1000000)
[    6.119685] checking generic (d0000000 410000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[    6.119688] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
[    6.119869] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    6.119919] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    6.124647] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    6.125440] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    6.143587] psmouse serio3: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x2e800/0x0, board id: 3146, fw id: 2004303
[    6.148805] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: a0:d3:7a:db:ae:84
[    6.167288] loop17: detected capacity change from 0 to 91496
[    6.167409] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[    6.167415] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:117:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[    6.177272] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio3/input/input10
[    6.178801] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.183301] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    6.190704] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input14
[    6.204353] intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
[    6.204364] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.204447] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    6.204474] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    6.223221] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.229394] loop18: detected capacity change from 0 to 133552
[    6.269689] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    6.293267] loop19: detected capacity change from 0 to 167456
[    6.322943] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    6.334415] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    6.355431] usb 1-9: Found UVC 1.00 device HP HD Camera (04ca:7053)
[    6.365431] input: HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/input/input15
[    6.365509] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    6.401750] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    6.401754] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    6.401756] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    6.401758] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    6.417492] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.200785] input: ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer as /devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input16
[    7.340962] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.374938] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20724: BIOS auto-probing.
[    7.375628] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: vmaster hook already present before cdev!
[    7.375843] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20724: line_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    7.375848] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.375851] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1d/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.375854] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    7.375855] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    7.375857] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    7.375859] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
[    7.375861] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x18
[    7.399282] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[    7.399361] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    7.399415] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[    7.399468] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
[    7.399521] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
[    7.399583] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
[    7.399645] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
[    7.399705] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
[    7.399758] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
[    7.500503] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    7.501523] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1430215 usecs
[    7.501554] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    7.512498] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10703 usecs
[    7.512621] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[    7.516492] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    7.517525] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[    7.518499] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 10 week 41 2018
[   95.389662] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.875:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=693 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.389669] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.875:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=693 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.392140] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.875:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=695 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.394351] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.879:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=697 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.402160] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.887:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=696 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.403458] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.887:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=699 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.411506] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.895:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=692 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.411513] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.895:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=692 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.411516] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.895:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=692 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.412630] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980177.895:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=700 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   95.814394] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   95.814399] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   95.814404] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   95.849058] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   96.273339] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   96.419557] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   96.510143] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   97.096923] loop20: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[   99.365165] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  100.179530] wlp2s0: authenticate with 3c:84:6a:aa:0d:3d
[  100.191021] wlp2s0: send auth to 3c:84:6a:aa:0d:3d (try 1/3)
[  100.197130] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  100.200891] wlp2s0: associate with 3c:84:6a:aa:0d:3d (try 1/3)
[  100.203022] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 3c:84:6a:aa:0d:3d (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=3)
[  100.206182] wlp2s0: associated
[  100.273117] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  123.309995] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  123.310004] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  123.310011] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  123.416445] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  126.151680] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  126.609309] kauditd_printk_skb: 49 callbacks suppressed
[  126.609312] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980209.096:61): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/15534/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1883 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  129.510521] audit: type=1326 audit(1650980212.019:62): auid=1001 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=1883 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fec7606f76d code=0x50000
[  131.632794] audit: type=1107 audit(1650980214.149:63): pid=755 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.6" pid=1883 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=774 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  131.633976] audit: type=1107 audit(1650980214.149:64): pid=755 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.6" pid=1883 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=774 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  131.674805] audit: type=1107 audit(1650980214.189:65): pid=755 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.6" pid=1883 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=774 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  131.676053] audit: type=1107 audit(1650980214.193:66): pid=755 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.6" pid=1883 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=774 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  132.199968] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980214.715:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=1883 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  140.967942] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980223.506:68): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=1883 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  140.998449] audit: type=1400 audit(1650980223.538:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu- software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=1883 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
[  141.509336] audit: type=1326 audit(1650980224.047:70): auid=1001 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=1883 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7fec760663cb code=0x50000
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am glad that you were able to solve the problem and you have written an answer so that others will find it helpful. Please do not put SOLVED/RESOLVED in the question title in this site. Click on the gray check mark ✓ next to the correct answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the question is correctly answered and help others.

Comment: Sorry it's te first time than I use Ask. Thanks to help me to use it smartly.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has some features that can help you diagnose these issues. Try doing:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

This will see which parts of the boot process are taking the longest time. Sometimes this can be the NetworkManager-wait-online.service. For some users issuing the command

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

may help.

Another useful command is:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

This will high light in red those items that are giving you problems or are taking longest. In my system is the Blueman-mechanism.service, which is starting up bluetooth. For me, this is sort of critical, so I have to liove with it!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try systemd-analyze blame but no informations after 6s.  You propose a second command but it's look like the first

Comment: not better after sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

Answer (score 0):

That's ok now !
Bootup and startup <30s !

The issue was in fstab.

```
utilisateur@gb-elite:~/Bureau$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=56e264bb-e854-4b2f-817a-876f814cd75c /               ext4   errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=49E5-0BC1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

With lsblk i discover there is no UUID=49E5-0BC1

```
utilisateur@gb-elite:~/Bureau$ lsblk -fe7
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL            FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                          
└─sda1      vfat         30A6-5C8A                              28,6G          0% /media/utilisateur/30A6-5C8A
nvme0n1                                                                      
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs   250   0D6E203260E38C70                                    
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                  
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4         56e264bb-e854-4b2f-817a-876f814cd75c  355,9G        19% /
```

So i have just to suppress the line
UUID=56e264bb-e854-4b2f-817a-876f814cd75c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
from fstab.

Thanks to Adrian Challinor to try to help me.